# VIES SOAP Request

Tags: vb.net, soap, request, xmlhttprequest

I am using vb.net and i want to make a soap request for getting data from VIES website
I am using this code:

```
Dim wc As New System.net.WebClient()
Dim req As String

req = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:urn=""urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types""><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><urn:checkVat><urn:countryCode>COUNTRY</urn:countryCode><urn:vatNumber>VATNUMBER</urn:vatNumber><urn:memberStateCode>MEMBERSTATECODE</urn:memberStateCode><urn:number>NUMBER</urn:number></urn:checkVat></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"
req = req.Replace("COUNTRY", countryCode)
req = req.Replace("VATNUMBER",vatNumber)
req = req.Replace("MEMBERSTATECODE", memberStateCode)
req = req.Replace("NUMBER", number)
response = wc.UploadString("http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatTestService.wsdl", req)
```

to make the request and eveything is fine for me untill I get to the point where I need to get the CONSULTATION NUMBER, that I can NOT find in my response.
Is something wrong with my code or what can I do, in order to get it?
I am sending different codes in the request. (searcher is different from the lookup)

I am sending a SOAP Request and sending the info from above and I deserialize the response and access the elements like this: xDocResponse.Descendants(Namespace+ "consultationNumber").FirstOrDefault.Value.ToString
In order to get the consultationNumber, but in my response there is no field named consultationNumber, so how can I get it?

Comment: Not sure exactly what your question is.  Where exactly is the consultation missing from?  a) The req that you are uploading, b)the response content being returned from  wc.uploadstring()?  If a) you simply need to add it as required by the other end, if b) you probably are better off contacting the developers for assistance

Comment: Also, you can import that wsdl as a service references into your solution, that will build a lot of functionality, document type requirments etc for you.

Comment: @Hursey I don't know how to do it actually in order to get it. It's missing from my response.

Comment: @Hursey I am willing to find the consultation number that we can also see on the website. I think in the response will be something like requestIdentifier? I found some documentation but didn't help me make the request work, so I am willing to find out what sould I change so that I can make the request work and give me the CONSULTATION NUMBER with the rest of the info: name, address, valid, etc.

Comment: Honestly, not really sure exactly what you are trying to do.  If the property is missing from the response it's simply because the developer of the SOAP service hasn't made it accessible.  Your options are contact the developer, perhaps you can convince them to add it to that end point, or perhaps there is a second endpoint that makes the data you require visible.